# Chrome-Extension: Running Content Editor on Client Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension, html-editor

I'm working on a very simple form filler with Chrome Extension to a spcific site.
I'm getting the name, subject and the message from the user, and just put it in the right places.

I've got a problem with the message part, because it uses an HTML editor. I want to be able to let the user create text message with `href` links using Microsoft Word or even Front Page and of course a content editor, and just copy the content the user made into the extension, and it will fill it in the right place on the site.

I tried using http://ckeditor.com/ but it can't work without a server. (Use the 1 Visual Studio create to test it).

Is there a content editor like ckeditor, that can work on client side too, and that I can use Javascript to get the info from the user?

I know this is a weird request, and even sound illogical, but is for a friend (and for learning).

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Editors based on `contenteditable` might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228957/whats-a-good-wysiwyg-editor-to-use-with-contenteditable

Comment: thank u, but do u have a direct link to the contenteditable? becuse the link in the page u gave me dosnt work any more (404)

Comment: @apsillers nvm found it, thanks i will check it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afther some days for serching the web i found this: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

it work only for html 5, and it amazing feature!

if any 1 have this wierd request too, this simple code with get your start:

```
 <div contenteditable="true">this is a smaple</div>
```

this attribute is what make the megic happend: `contenteditable="true"`

in that div, you can throw any thing from out side your work space. meaning, you can do a href with WORD, and just copy it to the div, and it will set it up for you!

1 thing that is still wierd, if you dont have borders to the div, it will not set 1 for you like normal text field or textarea. so if u dont see it, it dosnt mean is not there!

enjoy.